# Trying to Copy Excel Table with Autofilter returns error 424 Object required? [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to paste rows from one excel file to another, I'm new to VBA. My excel files are identical tables, since they are the same, both have an "ID" column, with the ID consisting of numbers. Some ID are blank, and these need to get filtered out.

Currently I have the following code:

```
iFile.Worksheets(1).Range("A3:AN" & lastRowIn).AutoFilter(13, "<>") _
oFile.Worksheets(1).Range ("A" & lastRowOt)
```

where "iFile" is the origin file, and oFIle is the destiny file. lastRowIn and LastRowOut are the number of the last row of each one of them.

When I remove the AutoFilter, it works no problem. But when its written as in the example, it gives

```
Run-time error "424"
Object Required
```

Comment: `AutoFilter` doesn't work that way. Maybe you're thinking of `AdvancedFilter`?

Comment: I didnt knew that function existed in VBA, i'll try